# Иконки классов в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image: Иконки классов]

Скачал проект с bitbucket, открыл в AndroidStudio. Что означают такие иконки классов? Проект запускается нормально, никаких ошибок не выдает.

Comment: не понятно, что там изображено. попробуйте идентифицировать по ссылке https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html

Comment: @Chubatiy значок Java там)

Comment: @Chubatiy Это значок файла java, но он должен быть голубым значком java класса. Т.е. Java файлы в проекте не определяются как java классы.

Comment: @iFr0z А из-за чего эти фалы не отображаются как классы?

Comment: забавно конечно, но даже в оф. доке https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html отсутствует данный значок...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я разобрался в проблеме. Я использовал Material Theme UI, и видно с последним обновлением студии этот плагин стал работать некорректно. Я перешел на стандартную тему и все иконки стали нормальными, стали отображаться и классы и интерфейсы.